# Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos Strogatz Question 4.4.3

Tags: nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics

Over dampened Pendulum System:
$$
mL^{2}\ddot{\theta } +b\dot{\theta } +mgL\sin \theta =\Gamma 
$$
First order approximation:

$$
b\dot{}+mgL\sin{}=Γ
$$

Nondimensionalize, diving through by mgL:

$$
\frac{b\dot{\theta }}{mgL} =\frac{\Gamma }{mgL} -\sin \theta 
$$

Let $$\tau =\frac{mgL}{b} t$$ and $$\gamma =\frac{\Gamma }{mgL}$$

Then

$$
\frac{d\theta }{d\tau } =\gamma -\sin \theta 
$$

The discussion in section 4.4 of Strogatz describes $\gamma$ as the dimensionless group that represents the applied torque to the gravitational torque. As $\gamma$ decreases to 1 a fixed point at pi/2 appears, as it goes lower stable and unstable pair appear from this fixed point.

I get what he's saying. I understand the system, but then he asks the following questions:

[image]

The solution manual only presents the answers to odd questions.
How are you supposed to represent $\frac{d\theta }{d\tau } =\gamma -\sin \theta$ against time when its a function of $\tau$?

I do not have a digital copy of the solution manual. However it shows a graph of $\dot{}$($\frac{\dot{d\theta }}{dt}$) vs $t$ notated at $\gamma = 100$. The graph is a straight line.

Unsure how he came to this result as $\dot{}$ is never a function of $\gamma$.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Hi @Moo No, not yet. I moved on in the book. I sort of get what he intuitively means. Just dont see how he analytically came to the graph in the book after he nondimensionalised the equation.